# How to validate a nested model object based on the state of the parent object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, activerecord

I am writing a wizard form in rails; e.g. multiple input pages for one model object.

The basics of my approach are those described in Ryan Bates' Multistep form railscast : http://railscasts.com/episodes/217-multistep-forms (in case anyone wants to know the WHY behind some of the code below).

The objects under scrutiny here are "Participant", which has one "Address"

My problem is that I only want to validate the nested object (Address) when the user is trying to progress past the address input screen. This is currently tracked via an attribute on the Participant model called "current_step"

So I have a Participant:

```
class Participant < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :address
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :address
  validates_presence_of :first_name, :last_name, :if => self.current_step == "name"
  ...
  def steps = %w[ name address confirm ] # the steps the wizard will follow
end
```

And an Address:

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :participant
  validates_presence_of :address1, :state, :suburb, :postcode #, :if => participant.current_step == "address"
end
```

The principle of this approach is the "create" action is called on the controller (not shown) for each step of the wizard, and it only validates a subset of the model when each step is processed.

Currently, when I complete the first screen ("name") and try and go onto the address step, the address validation is getting triggered, and I get sent back to the "name" screen with validation errors for blank address details.

So I have tried a number of approaches here, the final part of which was the commented out condition on Address validation shown above - this I've found doesn't work as I'm only building Participant->Address objects, but not saving them. Therefore `@participant.address` gets me the address object, but `@participant.address.participant` is null as the Address does not yet have a participant_id foreign key to lookup it's parent.

The reason for my struggles appears to be the inclusion of the super-handy `accepts_nested_attributes_for` method. I was expecting to use a `validates_associated` to be doing the validation, but I see that the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` tag both propagates form parameters nicely to create nested model objects, but also ensures the `participant#valid?` method calls down to the address validation in ALL situations.

So my dilemma is how to best use the `participant#valid?` method to valid the partially complete model, based off the `current_step` parameter in the participant ?

EDIT - updated to remove extra info, and distill down to the core problem

Comment: Just a guess, but have you tried

validates :address, :if => Proc.new {|participant| participant.current_step == 'name' }

Comment: One of the first things I tried - but as noted above (perhaps not too clearly, I admit) the address object has no participant until it's saved, so I was getting an error calling current_step on a nil class.

Comment: Add :inverse_of to your relationships, so the address object will have a reference to its participant when it's built.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Add a virtual attribute on your `Address` model:

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :participant
  attr_accessor :skip_validation
  validates_presence_of :address1, :state, :suburb, :postcode, 
                           :unless => :skip_validation 
end
```

Set the virtual attribute on the address object when `current_step` is set.

```
class Participant < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :address
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :address
  attr_accessor :current_step
  validates_presence_of :first_name, :last_name, 
                         :if => lambda {|r| r.current_step == "name"}


  def current_step=(value)
    unless (value == "address")
      address.skip_validation = true
    end    
    @current_step = value 
  end    
end
```

Comment: Nice idea. I'm calling the attribute `skip_validation` and use an `:unless` instead of `:if`, so the default is to validate. Works great so far.

Comment: Well, I removed my rails wizard several months back, and have since tackled more nested models gotchas, but it's great to come back to this and see what appears to be a solid answer to the problem. Thanks.

Comment: What I don't like about using `skip_validation` is that you don't really know why it's being used. I've come across code where I couldn't figure it out and the dev that wrote it had forgotten. :*(

Answer (score 0):

How about just assigning it in your controller before you call `participant.valid?`:

```
@participant.address.participant = @participant
```

Answer (score 0):

Although the ActiveRecord "validate" methods are very convenient, there's nothing to stop you from "rolling your own", perhaps using `before_save` hooks. You could replace your `validates_presence_of` validator on `Address` with a `before_save` hook which does validation only under certain conditions. Then `accepts_nested_attributes_for` presumably wouldn't see it.